# Keyboard shortcut to copy full file path of the current file

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like a keyboard shortcut to copy the full path of the currently open file. Do I need to add a new key binding, or is there an already existing shortcut?

I'm using a Mac.

Comment: most likely the command needed contains the word `path`, in the keybind GUI search for `path`, one of the few results is the command you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`, and search for the command `@command:copyFilePath`. If there is a keyboard shortcut set, it will be there. If not, you can set one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There an already existing shortcut.

> Shift + Alt + c

Comment: I cannot verify this, but on my Mac, Shift + Option + c does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Command + option + C to copy the path of a file